# Is it better to use Nib's or Code for views in iOS projects?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm working on a project right now and have been doing all of my views with code because I have a weird thought that nib's could be hard to work with a team (should I ever need a team for what I'm working on).

Is this irrational? What are some of the pitfalls or advantages of using code / nibs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the conditions, 
I generally use storyboards if I am the only working on that projects.
I will use xib if there are other working as well.

It wont be possible to merge the storyboard or xibs(or may be I don't know how to merge them).
I can write programmatically but it take too much time to do that stuff so instead of I prefer to work with xibs instead of doing programmatically and make sure that we work on different modules so that xibs not get merge conflicts, even if we got conflict I do that manually but thats rare in may case.

So its upto you what you prefer to use, do some more search on Google and you will find out more other opinions.